# Java running on Windows - How to exec cmd for commands not in PATH?

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu, cmd

I have a script (**DependencyExtractor** from [DependencyFinder](https://github.com/jeantessier/dependency-finder)) that I need to run using Java. So far, this is what I have:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("DependencyExtractor -xml -out output.xml input_folder/classes")
```

But this returns an error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "DependencyExtractor": CreateProcess error=2
```

If I [add DependencyFinder to the PATH](https://jeantessier.github.io/dependency-finder/Manual.html#Step4:PATH), everything works fine. **But how can I run it directly, without needing to deal with PATH** ?

PS: On Ubuntu 20 I can run with success using this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("path_to_DependencyFinder/bin/DependencyExtractor -xml -out output.xml input_folder/classes")
```

Where `path_to_DependencyFinder` is the path to the zip [downloaded here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=43305)

Comment: You can use the full path : `path_to_DependencyFinder/bin/DependencyExtractor.exe` in Windows also. Did you try that ? Also, remember to put the `.exe`.

Comment: @anacron Unfortunately, I don't have an exe file. DependencyFinder only provides the bash script, as linked in the question

Comment: Looks like there is a file with a `.bat` extension. You can run it with `cmd /c path_to_dep_finder_bat` command passed to the `exec()` method I think.

Comment: @anacron I searched for a `.bat` on their GitHub and on the zip, but couldn't find one. Which `.bat` file are you referring to?